# Get available option values for product collection

Tags: attributes, collection, product-attribute, product-collection

im currently working on a project where i have to find out the available option values for a product collection.
Basically like the layered navigation but for a specific product collection.

Example:
Attribute color has 5 different values. ( blue, yellow, red, orange, green )
I only have products in my shop that have the values "blue", "yellow" and "red" set.
So what i need is kind of like this.

```
$collection        = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$option_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
    ->setAttributeFilter(1)                        // id of color attribute
    ->setProductFilter($collection->getAllIds())   // the important part
    ->load();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean, for color red, you want to show all the products?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how it's been done in the layered navigation:

the responsible method is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute::getCount()`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve array with products counts per attribute option
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute $filter
 * @return array
 */
public function getCount($filter)
{
    // clone select from collection with filters
    $select = clone $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getSelect();
    // reset columns, order and limitation conditions
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);

    $connection = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    $attribute  = $filter->getAttributeModel();
    $tableAlias = sprintf('%s_idx', $attribute->getAttributeCode());
    $conditions = array(
        "{$tableAlias}.entity_id = e.entity_id",
        $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.attribute_id = ?", $attribute->getAttributeId()),
        $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.store_id = ?", $filter->getStoreId()),
    );

    $select
        ->join(
            array($tableAlias => $this->getMainTable()),
            join(' AND ', $conditions),
            array('value', 'count' => new Zend_Db_Expr("COUNT({$tableAlias}.entity_id)")))
        ->group("{$tableAlias}.value");

    return $connection->fetchPairs($select);
}
```

Unfortunately you can't use that straight away with any collection because it's too tightly coupled to the filter model, which again doesn't handle arbitrary product collections.

So your best option is probably to copy what you need from there into an own resource model like this (untested):

```
class Your_Extension_Model_Resource_Attribute extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    public function getCount($productCollection, $attributeCode, $storeId)
    {
        // clone select from collection with filters

        //----------------------------------------------------------------
        $select = clone $productCollection->getSelect();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------

        // reset columns, order and limitation conditions
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);

        $connection = $this->_getReadAdapter();

        //----------------------------------------------------------------
        $attribute  = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode($attributeCode);
        //----------------------------------------------------------------

        $tableAlias = sprintf('%s_idx', $attribute->getAttributeCode());
        $conditions = array(
            "{$tableAlias}.entity_id = e.entity_id",
            $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.attribute_id = ?", $attribute->getAttributeId()),

        //----------------------------------------------------------------
            $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.store_id = ?", $storeId),
        //----------------------------------------------------------------

        );

        $select
            ->join(
                array($tableAlias => $this->getMainTable()),
                join(' AND ', $conditions),
                array('value', 'count' => new Zend_Db_Expr("COUNT({$tableAlias}.entity_id)")))
            ->group("{$tableAlias}.value");

        return $connection->fetchPairs($select);
    }

}
```

And then call it like

```
$options = Mage::getResourceModel('your_extension/attribute')
    ->getCount($collection, 'color', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

`$options` will be an array with the values as key and number of occurances as value. Filtering out the 0's should not be a problem from there.

Answer (score 0):

I will try something like this

```
$collection        = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('color_attribute_code');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('color_attribute_code', 1/*id of color attribute*/);
```

For further detail about filtering collection please refere to: 
[Magento Wiki using collection](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)

regards